# Will this cause a retain cycle Swift?

Tags: swift, closures

I have this code and I'm questioning if I need to use a capture list to make my reference to `self` weak.

Right now I'm thinking that `getTextFileData` and `.main.async` are static methods, therefore, this will not cause a retain cycle. However, I do access the `games` property, kinda not sure.

```
    NPWebService.getTextFileData { (games, success) in
        if success {
            self.games = games
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.updateUI()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `DispatchQueue.main.async` does definitely **not** cause a retain cycle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This wouldn’t cause a retain *cycle* because it looks like a static method on a different type. So the `getTextFileData` method will temporarily retain the closure you are passing in until any asynchronous work is complete, and the closure will temporarily retain self.  But when the work is complete and the closure is done executing, those temporary retains will expire and automatic memory management can clean up as appropriate.

The danger of a retain cycle is when you have a closure the that references / captures self, and self also retains the closure, for example. Like this:

```
class GameController {
  var games: [Game]?
  // self retains the closure as a property
  let updateClosure:([Game], Bool)->() = {
    games, success in
    if success {
      self.games = games // and the closure captures self. Each retains each other indefinitely, this is a retain cycle and neither this closure nor self will ever be deallocated 
    }
  }

  func load() {
    NPWebService.getTextFileData(updateClosure)
  }
}
```

So normally weak self or unowned self in closure capture lists are only needed:

- if self or something retained by self will be retaining that closure (this is rarely the case when a closure is created locally and transiently at the call site to pass into a method as an argument)
- if for non-retain cycle reasons, the desired behavior is to allow self to be deallocated before some asynchronous work is completed, and before the closure is invoked. In this case the closure shouldn’t strongly capture self and instead should weakly capture it and check if it still exists before making use of self when the closure is invoked